# stylelint rule not working for the function URL

Tags: javascript, regex, stylelint

Am trying to add the rule for the **background-image** URL should start with images

```
background-image: url(ssasimages/dummy.svg);
```

Please find below the screenshot FYR.

It's not giving error, please someone help me to find what did wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rule unfortunately doesn't apply in your case.

It will only validate the *url scheme*, and not the whole url. If your url started with `data:`, or `http:` then the rule would be applied.

From [the docs for the function-url-scheme-whitelist rule](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/function-url-scheme-whitelist):

> A URL scheme consists of alphanumeric, +, -, and . characters. It can appear at the start of a URL and is followed by :.

To get your desired functionality in stylelint you'd need to [write a plugin](https://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins). You could use [the source of the function-url-scheme-whitelist rule](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/lib/rules/function-url-scheme-whitelist/index.js) as a good starting point.

Comment: Hey @tekniskt thanks for your info. should I raise PR for this after write plugin?

Comment: Already raised PR for this https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/pull/4816 and as you said end of the PR they need to write a plugin for my use case. Can u pls help me how could i take this into plugin.